# Azure Data Explorer Dashboard - Display for time zone showing selected time range (period)

Tags: azure, kql, adx

As of today, to display the current time range selected in a dashboard is displayed like so:
`print strcat(format_datetime(datetime_utc_to_local(_startTime, 'Europe/Oslo'), 'yyyy-MM-dd [HH:mm:ss]'), " - ", format_datetime(datetime_utc_to_local(_endTime, 'Europe/Oslo'), 'yyyy-MM-dd [HH:mm:ss]'))`, however I would like the tile to be able to detect the time zone selected in the dashboard environment.

Is there any built-in variable that shows this information, or workaround to satisfy the request?

Attempted to find any documentation on such variable without luck. Also attempted using now() and ago() with the time range to see if it adjusted with time zone, however it seems like it does not  work as expected and did not adjust with time zone.